# QNetworkAccessManager - How to send "PATCH" request

Tags: qt, httprequest, qnetworkaccessmanager, qtnetwork, qnetworkrequest

I am trying to send a "PATCH" request to my firebase application.As far as I read QNetworkManager doesn't support "Patch" request.

How can I send "PATCH" request ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So we are clear that there is no method in QNetworkAccessManager named "patch"
Therefore I have used "sendCustomRequest" but with QBuffer. Because QNetworkManager requires a QIODevice object.

```
QString destination="";
currentNode.replace(QString("/").append(latestNode),"");
destination
        .append(host)
        .append(currentNode)
        .append(".json");
QString jsonString=QString(QString("{").append("\"").append(latestNode).append("\"").append(":").append("\"").append(str).append("\"").append(QString("}")));
QNetworkRequest request(destination);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
qDebug()<<jsonString;
QBuffer *buffer=new QBuffer();
buffer->open((QBuffer::ReadWrite));
buffer->write(jsonString.toUtf8());
buffer->seek(0);
manager->sendCustomRequest(request,"PATCH",buffer);
qDebug()<<"posted";
```

Comment: Aside: using operator `+` instead of all those `append`s results in clearer and more maintainable code.

Comment: Note that the `QBuffer` needs to be created as a pointer (as Aykut rightly did) and not on the stack, otherwise it might be garbage collected before the request has time to be executed, leading to very hard to debug issues.

Comment: If you want to use `QBuffer`, you can make the code simpler (as per Qt source code for `QNetworkAccessManager`) and replace the calls to `write` & `seek` with `setData()`. However `QNetworkAccessManager::sendCustomRequest()` has a variant that takes a `QByteArray`, so you could bypass `QBuffer` and simply put `manager->sendCustomRequest(request,"PATCH",jsonString.toUtf8());`

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QNetworkRequest request("http://<domain>/<path>/");
QHttpMultiPart* multipart = new QHttpMultiPart();
//... Add your data in multipart
manager->sendCustomRequest(request, "PATCH", multipart);
```

Answer (score 2):

As `QNetworkAccessManager` does not support PATCH implicitly, I've created the following class `QNetworkAccessManagerWithPatch` that does. Use it in place of `QNetworkAccessManager` and you'll have the same 3 variants for `patch()` as there are for `post()`, `put()`, etc.

Get the Github gist here: https://gist.github.com/paulmasri/efafb8ee350a8ce84a6657a30eb4eb8a

Or take the code directly from here: (save as `QNetworkAccessManagerWithPatch.h`)

```
#pragma once

#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

class QNetworkAccessManagerWithPatch : public QNetworkAccessManager
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit QNetworkAccessManagerWithPatch(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR)
        : QNetworkAccessManager(parent) {}

    QNetworkReply* patch(const QNetworkRequest &request, QIODevice *data)
    { return sendCustomRequest(request, "PATCH", data); }
    QNetworkReply* patch(const QNetworkRequest &request, const QByteArray &data)
    { return sendCustomRequest(request, "PATCH", data); }

#if QT_CONFIG(http)
    QNetworkReply *patch(const QNetworkRequest &request, QHttpMultiPart *multiPart)
    { return sendCustomRequest(request, "PATCH", multiPart); }
#endif
};
```

Comment: While the point of stack overflow is not to get free code, I like it when you are in the middle of building a solution and is blocked by an distracting issue with the framework (or whatever), and then... suddenly a heavenly developer shares you some code that allows you to focus on the actual solution you were working on.... Thanks mate.